# Take a screenshot of a full browser window with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a possibility to take a screenshot using Selenium Webdriver.

It takes screenshot of the whole area of a **web page** but the **browser window (boarder) is not included in this screenshot.**

Is there a way to take screenshot with Selenium Webdriver so the whole browser window is captured?

I want to see all the status bars, tabs and buttons.

It's possible to do with .NET but then there is a chance that it will screen something else (if for example browser was minimized) so I'd like to do it with selenium.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, this [isn't possible](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#screen-capture) using WebDriver:

> WebDriver provides the Take Screenshot command to capture the
>   top-level browsing context’s initial **viewport**, and a command Take
>   Element Screenshot for doing the same with the visible region of an
>   element’s **bounding rectangle** after it has been scrolled into view.

I don't know how vital this is to you, but you could potentially configure your browser to open at a fixed location, with a fixed size (via WebDriver), take a full-screen screenshot ([Java code](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-take-screen-shots-in-java-taking-screenshots-java/); alternatively automate the "Print Screen" button), and use what you know about the window bounds to crop the full-screen image down to include just the window.

It might not be perfect if you have to support multiple operating systems and browsers, but you could tweak it to be quite accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with Selenium Webdriver, to get the screenshot of whole web browser window. However you can still make it work by using Ashot

The article how can we do that can be checked [here](http://blog.xebia.in/2015/07/05/capture-full-page-screenshot-for-chrome-browser-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Hope this helps :).

Comment: The link in the answer is broken at the moment.